# Can someone explain to me what this code does?

Tags: c++, c

This is actually a question from an exam and I don't quite understand what that typedef does if someone can explain i would be grateful.

```
typedef int (*funcptr_t)(int);

int myfoo(int i) {
   printf("%d\n", i + 1);
   return i;
}

funcptr_t foo(int i) {
   printf("%d\n", i + 1);
   return myfoo;
}

int main() {
   funcptr_t fooptr = foo(0);
   fooptr(10);
   printf("%p %p\n", fooptr, myfoo);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with *function pointers*?

Comment: yes, I am, I see that I have a function pointer in the typedef

Comment: `foo` returns a pointer to a function `myfoo`.. So first it will call `foo` which prints i + 1, then returns `myfoo`.. Therefore `fooptr = myfoo`.. so `fooptr(10)` actually calls `myfoo(10)`

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: So this is what that `typedef` does - it is defining a type which is function pointer

Comment: Pedantic question - is it really "defining a type" or just giving an existing type a nicer name?

Comment: @SeanBright That's a good question.  It's certainly not defining a type like `int` is defined, for example.

Comment: @SeanBright Dunno. It is listed under "Type definitions" section: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.8.

Comment: It doesn't really matter for this question, but it's customary to tag with *one* language, the one you're using.

Comment: no it does not define a new type. The original type and the alias are exactly the same type

Comment: The `typedef` can be considered making a *synonym*.  So one can type `funcptr` instead of the less desirable syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int (*funcptr)(int);` would declare `functptr` as a [pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `int`](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20%28*funcptr%29%28int%29%3B).

`typedef int (*funcptr_t)(int);` declares `functptr_t` as the **type** "pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `int`.

The typedef allows you to declare/define `foo` with `funcptr_t foo(int i)` rather than the classical but arguably more confusing:

```
int (*foo(int i))(int)
```

Comment: Yes, the classical way is hideous.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I would never say that. In even kind of like it. :D

Comment: `typedef` is what I call "classical" ;). `using` allows for a much more readable syntax

Comment: Yeah, I would disagree on the use of "classical" word here.

Comment: thank you, but there is still one thing that I am missing, why is it calling ```fooptr(10)``` and not ```(*fooptr)(10)``` since ```fooptr``` is a pointer ```(*fooptr)``` would be the actual function ?

Comment: @LongClaw Old (pre-standard) C required that function pointer should be called with the asterisk. The first standard dropped that requirement. `*` applied to a function pointer doesn't really do anything (other than a type adjustment)  or fetch any value. The call is made via a pointer regardless of whether you do `fooptr()`, `(*fooptr)()`, `(******fooptr)()`, or `(**&****&***fooptr())()` (allowing all these forms is kind of a weird quirk of C). Even direct calls are made specified via function-to-function-ptr decay (and call instructions in assembly take function addresses too).